# Problem starting my machine

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, software-update, screen

So, a while ago something happened to my MacBook Pro such that when I boot it, it doesn’t turn on the screen - it hasn’t been a problem, because I simply closed the screen, waited for it to go to sleep, and then opened it again;  the screen would be working and I could login.

So, today I decided to update to High Sierra, and now it won’t turn on the screen whatever I do - I suspect it has to do with the startup screen when you install a new OS. It’s HDMI port doesn’t work, and I can’t find my mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter, so I don’t know what to do.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: MacBook Pro Model?  When you turn on, do you see the Apple logo?  If you hold Cmd-V (Verbose Mode), do you see the boot messages?

Comment: Have you attempted to reset your device's SMC and NVRAM?

Comment: The screen simply doesn’t turn on, so I don’t see anything. I tried holding Cmd-Opt-P-R on startup, and I heard the second boot up, but the screen was still turned off. Is there a way to skip the introduction to High Sierra? If I can do that, I think I can get it working